# How to get @solana/web3.js to access the RPC endpoints through a proxy?

Tags: web3.js, proxy

In some countries, Solana RPC endpoints are blocked.

"https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com" and "https://api.devnet.solana.com/" are both blocked in China.

When I'm trying to connect, I'm getting this error:

```
 https://api.devnet.solana.com/ failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.240.182.55:443
```

How to get @solana/web3.js to access the RPC endpoints through a proxy?

Comment: In some countries, solana nodes cannot be accessed, how to set solana web3.js to access through proxy

Answer (score 8):

First you'd need to find/buy a proxy server you can use. Once you've got one, add it to your projects `.env` file like this:

```
HTTP_PROXY=http://user:pass@ip:port
```

You should then be able to to use it like this:

```
import { clusterApiUrl, Connection } from "@solana/web3.js";
import { TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID } from "@solana/spl-token";
import { TokenListProvider} from '@solana/spl-token-registry';
import { log } from 'console';
import { HttpsProxyAgent } from 'hpagent';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import { config } from 'dotenv';
config();

const proxy = process.env.HTTP_PROXY;
const proxyAgent = new HttpsProxyAgent ({ proxy });

const solanaConnection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta"), {
  commitment: 'confirmed',
  fetch: async (input, options) => {
    const processedInput =
    typeof input === 'string' && input.slice(0, 2) === '//'
      ? 'https:' + input
      : input;    

    const result = await fetch(processedInput, {
      ...options,
      agent: proxyAgent,
    });

    log('RESPONSE STATUS', result.status);
    return result;
  },
});

const walletToQuery = process?.argv[2];
if(!walletToQuery) {
  throw new Error('No wallet address given');
}

// An example taken from some article online
async function getTokenRegistry(){
    const tokenListProvider =  new TokenListProvider;
    const tokens = await tokenListProvider.resolve();
    const tokenList = tokens.filterByClusterSlug('mainnet-beta').getList();
    return(tokenList);
}

async function getTokenAccounts(wallet, solanaConnection) {
    const filters = [
        {
          dataSize: 165,    // size of account (bytes)
        },
        {
          memcmp: {
            offset: 32,     // location of our query in the account (bytes)
            bytes: wallet,  // our search criteria, a base58 encoded string
          },            
        }];
    const accounts = await solanaConnection.getParsedProgramAccounts(
        TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, // new PublicKey("TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA")
        {filters: filters}
    );
    console.log(`Found ${accounts.length} token account(s) for wallet ${wallet}.`);
    const tokenList = await getTokenRegistry();
    accounts.forEach((account, i) => {
        // Parse the account data
        const parsedAccountInfo = account.account.data;
        const mintAddress = parsedAccountInfo["parsed"]["info"]["mint"];
        const tokenBalance = parsedAccountInfo["parsed"]["info"]["tokenAmount"]["uiAmount"];
        // Find this token in the Token Registry
        const tokenName = tokenList.find(token=>token.address === mintAddress);
        // Log results
        console.log(`Token Account No. ${i + 1}: ${account.pubkey.toString()}`);
        console.log(`--Token Mint: ${mintAddress}`);
        if(tokenName) {console.log(`--Name: ${tokenName.name}`)}
        console.log(`--Token Balance: ${tokenBalance}`);
    });
}
getTokenAccounts(walletToQuery, solanaConnection);
```

*Note:* To run the above you'd need to install the required packages:

```
 - @solana/spl-token
 - @solana/spl-token-registry
 - @solana/web3.js
 - dotenv
 - hpagent
 - node-fetch
```

And then pass in a wallet address.

Example:

```
yarn install
node <FILENAME> <WALLET_ADDRESS>
```

Comment: This is a great answer (adding a custom agent to a connection). I'd only suggest using the built in `getTokenAccountsByOwner()` on `Connection` vs rolling your own with filtered program accounts. Less confusing for new users.

Comment: Thanks :)
That's probably a better suggestion. If you have time would you mind editing my answer and adding the implementation how you imagine in? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Connection, clusterApiUrl, Keypair, PublicKey,} from "@solana/web3.js";
import { HttpsProxyAgent } from 'hpagent';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import { config } from 'dotenv';
config();
(async () => {
    const proxy = process.env.HTTP_PROXY || "";
    console.log("proxy:", proxy)
    const proxyAgent = new HttpsProxyAgent ({ proxy });
    const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta"), {
        commitment: 'confirmed',
        fetch: async (input, options) => {
            const processedInput =
                typeof input === 'string' && input.slice(0, 2) === '//'
                    ? 'https:' + input
                    : input;

            const result = await fetch(processedInput, {
                ...options,
                agent: proxyAgent,
            });

            console.log('RESPONSE STATUS', result.status);
            return result;
        },
    });

    let latestBlockhash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();//
    console.log("latestBlockhash:", latestBlockhash)

    let base58publicKey = new PublicKey('9nEBir5mYz5yAnAtuZsuBxwfC7SayWZTMnyCmmTsUknf');
    console.log(base58publicKey.toBase58());

    let nonceAccountInfo = await connection.getAccountInfo(
        base58publicKey,
        'confirmed'
    );

    console.log("nonceAccountInfo:", nonceAccountInfo)

})()
```

Comment: to improve the quality of this answer, consider annotating this code to describe the changes you needed to make from your original to make it work