# Add custom proxy agent to solana connection

Tags: web3.js, typescript, proxy

I would like to know how can I add a proxy agent to a RPC connection in TypeScript ( I've already checked this question [How to get @solana/web3.js to access the RPC endpoints through a proxy?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/445/how-to-get-solana-web3-js-to-access-the-rpc-endpoints-through-a-proxy) but it ended up not working.

If anyone can provide an example, it'll be really helpful.

thanks.